# Python threading.start startup time

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make a little load testing script that runs a whole stack of operations in parallel but I am finding that the way I am starting threads seems to depend on how much work is in the the thread.

That is if I increase the amount of work the thread needs to do the longer the startup takes, can someone have a look at the below and let me know what I am doing wrong.

This is how I am starting my threads:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print i, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    t = Thread(target=make_request())
    t.start()
```

And here is the make_request()

```
def make_request():
    #global request_count
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        data = {'poll':'testpoll','option':random.choice(vote_options)}
        resp = requests.post("http://localhost:6223/create",data=data)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            request_count += 1
```

Basically I find if I increase the range in the make_request() the slower each thread starts.

Comment: If my answer below is correct, don't forget to accept the answer (click the check-mark under the 'vote up/down' button so it turns 'green') -- this indicates to others who may come across this question that you have the answer you need/want, and it gives me a small bump in rep (which makes me feel good!  =P).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part (most) of the problem you are seeing is that, when you set the `target` argument inside your `Thread()` class, you are invoking your function `make_request()`.  What this means to you is that, EVEN BEFORE you get to `Thread.start()`, you have kicked-off your function because when you **registered your call back** with Thread() you have also invoked the function (thus the longer 'start times'); realistically, you set `target` to `None` because your function returns `None`.  So the Thread() isn't really running anything in a thread!

Change it so it looks like:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print i, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    t = Thread(target=make_request)
    t.start()
```

Here is a good tutorial that might help you:

> http://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Comment: That is great thanks, sometimes it is the small things one misses!